# Updating string array in function - C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am writing C function, which updates array of strings, only if given elements are unique. I have implemented this function like this:

```
char *cities[100];

/* adds 2 names if they're unique instances and updates total number of cities names
if necessary */

int addCity(char* city1, char* city2, char** arr, int amount) {
    int toReturn = amount;
    int i;
    int flag1 = 0;
    int flag2 = 0;

    // checking whether first city already exists
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], city1) == NULL) {
            flag1 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag1 == 0) {
        arr[amount] = city1;
        toReturn++;
    }
    // 2nd city
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], city2) == NULL) {
            flag2 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag2 == 0 && flag1 == 1) {
        arr[amount] = city2;
        toReturn++;
    }
    if (flag2 == 0 && flag1 == 0) {
        arr[amount+1] = city2;
        toReturn++;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

It looks that I get some warnings(comparison between pointer and integer) when trying to compare element of String array and String itself. How can I get rid of that? And overall, what else can be improved in this function?

In addition, I doubt about arr[amount] = city1, but when i use strcpy() program does not work at all.

Comment: There is no string type in C. It is an array of `char` with specific conventions. However, your code does not use an array of that, but **pointers**. A pointer is not an array (nor a "string").

Comment: @Unknown  It is unclear if the two cities are equal each other do you need to add one of them?

Comment: @Olaf I understand that. I could say I use array of pointers to char, I just named it so to be simplier to read :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Basically, I give to the function two cities which are NOT equal and I have to include them both (if they're not existing in array yet).

Comment: Problem is that beginners tend to adopt such bad habits.

Comment: Doesn't that repeated chunk of code cry out for the use of a function from within the function you've just written?  It should — though maybe you've not yet got attuned to such refinements in style.  You also seem to be double incrementing `toReturn` — once while adding a city and again afterwards when you check whether a city was added.  You only need one of the two.  If you use a (sub)function, it can return 0 if it was not added and 1 if it was (the function would return the number of added city names, in other words).  And you aren't incrementing `amount` when you need to.

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you need is the following

```
char *cities[100];

/* adds 2 names if they're unique instances and updates total number of cities names
if necessary */

int addCity( const char *city1, const char *city2, char **arr, int amount ) 
{
    int i;

    // checking whether first city already exists
    i = 0;
    while ( i < amount && strcmp( arr[i], city1 ) != 0 ) i++;

    if ( i == amount )
    {
        arr[amount] = malloc( strlen( city1 ) + 1 );
        if ( arr[amount] ) strcpy( arr[amount++], city1 );
    }

    // 2nd city
    i = 0;
    while ( i < amount && strcmp( arr[i], city2 ) != 0 ) i++;

    if ( i == amount )
    {
        arr[amount] = malloc( strlen( city2 ) + 1 );
        if ( arr[amount] ) strcpy( arr[amount++], city2 );
    }

    return amount;
}
```

As for your code then these conditions in the if statements

```
if (strcmp(arr[i], city1) == NULL)
if (strcmp(arr[i], city2) == NULL)
```

are wrong. There should be

```
if (strcmp(arr[i], city1) == 0)
if (strcmp(arr[i], city2) == 0)
```

Also after this code block

```
if (flag1 == 0) {
    arr[amount] = city1;
    toReturn++;
}
```

you should also increase `amount` because it is used below as an index in the array of pointers.

These two conditions

```
if (flag2 == 0 && flag1 == 1) {
if (flag2 == 0 && flag1 == 0) {
```

are equivalent to condition

```
if (flag2 == 0) {
```

And it seems you should dynamically allocate memory for each added city.

As for me then I would use the following order of the function parameters

```
int addCity( char **arr, int amount, const char *city1, const char *city2 );
```

Or even the function could be defined the following way

```
int addCity( char **arr, int amount, const char *city )
{
    int i;

    // checking whether the city already exists
    i = 0;
    while ( i < amount && strcmp( arr[i], city ) != 0 ) i++;

    if ( i == amount )
    {
        arr[amount] = malloc( strlen( city ) + 1 );
        if ( arr[amount] ) strcpy( arr[amount++], city );
    }

    return amount;
}
```

and called separatly two times for each added city.

Answer (score 1):

First `strcmp` return an integer. So don't compare it to `NULL`. `NULL` is a pointer value. So instead do a compare to `0`.

```
if (strcmp(arr[i], city1) == 0)
```

Your main problem is however that you assign pointers passed as arguments into your `cities`. That is a major problem as the pointers will (likely) go out of scope soon.

You need to allocate memory and then do a `strcpy`. Something like:

```
if (flag1 == 0) {
    char* tmp = malloc(strlen(city) + 1); // add 1 for zero termination
    strcpy(tmp, city);
    arr[amount] = tmp;
    toReturn++;
}
```

And... don't forget to `free` the memory when done with it.

Comment: And don't forget to check for successful allocation before copying.  Or consider using `strdup()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (strcmp(arr[i], city1) == NULL) {
```

should be

```
    if (strcmp(arr[i], city1) == 0 ) {
```

Similarly, use

```
    if (strcmp(arr[i], city2) == 0 ) {
```

---

Whether you should use

```
    arr[amount] = city1;
```

or

```
    strcpy(arr[amount], city1);
```

depends on how memory for those two objects are managed. It's hard to suggest anything on that without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: I am reading these (city1, city1) from file while !EOF and calling this function everytime. My intention is that each name would be represented in array without repetition. Maybe I should use memmory allocation and strcpy in this case?

Comment: @Unknown, that is useful information but not enough to suggest a solution.

Comment: Another distinctly plausible alternative treatment is `arr[amount++] = strdup(city1);` — but there isn't enough information to  be sure that it is correct either.